# During a Cycles render an object behind glass looks striped

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency, glass

Using Cycles I rendered a object inside a tube (it's glass material). The problem is the object edges are striped as shown here:

[image]

The same thing happened for another project too:

[image]

In the first render I tried different options but the issue is still there. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is the glass object shading smooth or flat?

Comment: shading is flat

Comment: change it to smooth and test again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the object with the glass material has smooth shading.
You can change the shading of the object from the default flat shading by pressing  <kbd>Space</kbd>  and search for "Shade Smooth"